# Adding markers to splunk graphs

Tags: splunk

If I have a datasource of individual log changes captured by splunk, what's a good technique to add these as markers on top of a generic graph chart? (ex. a change which would impact traffic).

Comment: Need more information... can you add: An exemple of log, what kind of chart do you need and what is a "marker" for you?

Comment: For example if I look at this https://www.google.com/finance?q=SHA%3A000001&ei=nlR3VvD6Ooa-U_vEgMgE Google Finance chart I have the raw data and then there are markers representing some news labeled as letters. This is the type of effect I'd like to achieve (the log can be anything, let's say it's a change in a firewall configuration which has a timestamp in the line).

Comment: I don't know how to put all markers at the bottom of the chart but if they can be on the line itself you can create two series on the timechart one is a line chart and the second is a plot chart. For the plot chart, you just need to restrict your data to the "markers" with filter. So that, you will have your markers over your line chart. Do you need to have a specific label on this markers? (like "A", "B" ...)

Comment: No need to be labeled, I think the plot chart is a good idea and should do the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is special function to do this in Splunk, its called Chart Overlay.
https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/Chartcontrols#Chart_overlay

Without more specifics of searches, no more specific help can be provided.